# How to create a random unique file directly in /tmp using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bash

I am writing an application that creates and places a logfile in */tmp* and afterwards moves this logfile to another directory. Unfortunately I faced some issues with this implementation and I would like to make this logfile more unique.

I came across `mktemp`, which would automatically create a file in */tmp*. Perfect, just what I need! Unfortunately I cannot seem to get it to work in Ruby. I have tried the following without success:

```rb
def temporary_logfile
    @temporary_logfile = `mktemp "#{File.basename($PROGRAM_NAME)}_#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')}.logXXXX"`
end
```

I expected to see my logfile in */tmp* but unfortunately nothing happens. I wonder what I did wrong?

The next step would be to use `slice!` to remove the random generated characters from `mktemp` from the logfile name and than move the file somewhere else.

Comment: `SecureRandom.uuid` perhaps?

Comment: Is [`Tempfile`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) from the standard library what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Tempfile`: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html

```
file = Tempfile.new('foo')
begin
   # ...do something with file...
ensure
   file.close
   file.unlink   # deletes the temp file
end
```

Example is taken directly from the docu.